# "I done [past verb]" or "I done [present verb]" grammar

Tags: grammar, dialect, non-standard-english

So I came across these two weird sentences in some Hip-hop songs and I couldn't figure out in any way that what grammar they're following and the meanings were also really confusing for me.

The first one:

> **I done said** a lot of thing in my day

following the grammar: `Subject + Done + Past Verb`

The reference link: [Lucky you By Eminem [The beginning of verse 2]](https://genius.com/Eminem-lucky-you-lyrics)

and the second one:

> **I done quit** chicken heads cold turkey and started slowly roasting 'em

following the grammar: `Subject + Done + Simple Verb`

The reference link: [Evil twin By Eminem [The beginning of verse 1]](https://genius.com/Eminem-evil-twin-lyrics)

**And my questions are:**

- What were the original sentences in these two cases in terms of grammar?
- What tenses are they indicating and what are the ways to identify them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Said* and *quit* are not tensed verbs here but past participles. The construction *done V<sup>PaPpl</sup>* is a non-standard but (in US dialects) very common vernacular alternative to the perfect construction:

> I have said a lot of things in my day ...
>   I have quit chicken heads cold turkey ...

Compare

> My momma done told me —*Blues in the Night*
>   Done laid around and stayed around this old town too long —*Gotta Travel On*

Note that this construction is largely confined to perfective and active uses; continuative and passive uses are usually expressed with bare *been* rather than *done been*.

Comment: Although you could've added some examples for the continuative and passive cases.

Comment: @DevinHudson did you have those in your original question? Asking the correct question is the first step.